# Normal subgroup $H$ and order of double coset $HgH$

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite group and $H$ a sugroup of $G$. Show that $H$ is normal if and only if all the double cosets $HgH$ for every $g\in G$ have equal number of elements.

Comment: I only need to show that if the double classes have the same number of elements then H is normal. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h\in H$ then the double coset $HhH$ is $H$, so suppose that all double cosets have size $|H|$.

Take $g\in G$.  The right coset $Hg$ is contained in the double coset $HgH$ (just take the right hand multiplier to be $e$.  But $|Hg|=|H|$ so we must have $Hg=HgH$.  Similarly $gH=HgH$ whence $Hg=gH$ and we are done.